# Error on update can't get it fixed Err:8 & after the first part of post got this Err:7

Tags: gnome, 20.04, deb, archive, epiphany

Results of `sudo apt update` :

```
Err:8 http://archiver.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                              
  Temporary failure resolving 'archiver.ubuntu.com'
Fetched 433 kB in 20s (21.6 kB/s)     
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archiver.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archiver.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
AND AFTER POSTING TOP DID ANOTHER CHECK AND RUN "sudo apt-get update
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Err:7 http://archiver.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                              
  Temporary failure resolving 'archiver.ubuntu.com'
Hit:8 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease                               
Fetched 433 kB in 20s (21.2 kB/s)                 
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archiver.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archiver.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: @karel I think the issue is slightly different, in that they had a total misspelling.  Just a thought :)

Comment: meaning? what would this issue be? or thoughts of what i need to look into?  also i dont have issue to resolve yet, but in research..VPN. firewall. antivirus? what do you recommend.. any links on good tutorials or groups of edcuators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL is wrong.  It's `archive.ubuntu.com` not `archiver.ubuntu.com`.

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and replace instances of 'archiver' with 'archive'.  You can do this with through the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i.backup 's/archiver\.ubuntu\.com/archive\.ubuntu\.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

It will prompt you for your user password, you won't see the characters get entered but it IS accepting your password entry.  Once it executes the command, it'll fix the misspellings in place, and make a backup of the original file at `/etc/apt/sources.list.backup` as well.

Once done, run `sudo apt update` and it SHOULD work as expected.

Comment: awesome didnt even see that "r" in there reading past it..thanks new to this appreciate the quick feed back

Comment: Thomas, feeling stupid here now.  do i do that through the terminal or the desktop? where and how?  Any good tutorials. desktop clean up. and messed setting my vpn up too...

Comment: @ZZ I can't help with the desktop cleanup and VPN such right now, as your question here is limited to the `sources.list` issue for apt.  There are no complete tutorials for everything.  I'm going to suggest you post individual issues for those other issues.  I did, however, edit my answer to provide you a way to fix it in one go, without issue.  This should then fix your `apt` issue.  And if it does, please select this answer as the solution with the checkbox underneath the voting arrows to mark it as the solution.  (Run `sudo apt update` again after executing my command!)

Comment: it worked for "get:7" so do i check box becasuse now i have tha same error on 16--Err:16 http://archiver.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease             
  Could not resolve 'archiver.ubuntu.com'
Fetched 1,166 kB in 6s (202 kB/s)     
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archiver.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archiver.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: GOT IT.. TOOK A COUPLE MORE TIMES ON THE NEXT LINES.. BUT GOT IT JUST REPEATED IT. THANKS sorry i didnt see the command line from beginning...a little slow dropped on my head

Comment: No worries, I might've needed to make a revision to the sed, however I'm glad it helps :)